# what is a good way of passing parameters to SimpleJdbcTemplate

Tags: jdbctemplate

being pretty new to Spring and Jdbc, I am looking at a code from a Spring book and it is like this:

```
public voidaddSpitter(Spitterspitter){
jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_INSERT_SPITTER,
spitter.getUsername(),
spitter.getPassword(),
spitter.getFullName(),
spitter.getEmail(),
spitter.isUpdateByEmail());
spitter.setId(queryForIdentity());
}
```

Ok, so first param should be my SQL statement, but for the second param well does it get ugly in the code if there are like 15 columns in my table and I want to write 15 lines of those .get() methods? is there any nices/cleaner way of passing these?

Comment: The is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016753/is-there-a-generic-way-of-getting-columns-in-resultsset-of-maprow, and the answer is also the same.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values into an Object List (in a helper method ?) and convert it into an array while passing to update().

For eg:

```
List<Object> insertValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
....
insertValues.add(spitter.getUsername());
....

jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_INSERT_SPITTER, insertValues.toArray());
```